# ls or ll listing without permissions and hardlinks

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, ls

I need recursive listing of directories for my DVD backups. The prefect format is following:

```
Name of the directory:
subdirectory0/
subdirectory1/
size date time name0.txt
size date time name1.sh
size date time name2.odt
```

I got it with this crazy command:

```
ls -alFRgGv --time-style='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --group-directories-first | sed -r 's/^[drwx-]{10} *[0-9]* //;/^total /d;/.*\.{1,2}\/$/d ';
```

Please, is there any other way how to omit permissions and hard links in ls output? ("ls", not with the command "find")

Post scriptum:

There are some crazy numbers after total. There is "total 18" and only 2 files in the directory. Are those all hard links together?

Comment: Total is the "total number of file system blocks" which are probably 512-byte blocks.   So 18/2 = 9kb, which seems reasonable for a couple of files and a directory.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to produce the output you want with the U18.04LTS version of `ls`.  To get what you want will take writing a script to generate the output you want or to filter the `ls` output so it is close enough.  For a filter look at `sed` regex replacements.

Comment: Read `man stat`. You can specify your own output format.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: So, as I see your answers, Sirs, there is no way how to switch off permissions and hardlinks out of the ll... :-(  PS. Cyrus, you are rights. I did not want it to parse, but switch off via parameters. PS. Chick - thanks for explanation of the total meaning. PS. Waltinator - yes, stat is good, but I looked for faster way how to get it without much programming... Anyway, thank you. It is fain to have smart heads around to brainstorm. :-) I always run backups at the end of a year so, that is why I needed.